# Getting syntax error on a line with a label by itself in MARIE assembly

Tags: assembly, marie

I'm getting this error, `SyntaxError:L3 - Incorrect form`, on my MARIE code and I dont know how to fix it. For reference here is the code

```
ORG 000

PTR,  
JUMP Begin

DEC 2

NODE1,
DEC 10  / NODE VALUE
DEC 4   / POINTER TO THE LINKED LIST
        / ADDRESS TO THE NEXT NODE

NODE2,
DEC 20
DEC 6   / ADDRESS TO THE NEXT NODE

NODE3,
DEC 30  / NODE VALUE

NODE4,
DEC 8   / ADDRESS TO THE NEXT NODE
DEC 40  / NODE VALUE
DEC 10  / POINTER TO THE LINKED LIST

NODES,
DEC 50  / ADDRESS TO THE NEXT NODE
        / NODE VALUE
        / ADDRESS = 0, END OF LINKED LIST
DEC 0

Begin,
    LOAD NODE1
    OUTPUT
    LOAD PTR
    OUTPUT
    LOAD NODE2
    OUTPUT
    LOAD PTR
    OUTPUT
    LOAD NODE3
    OUTPUT
    LOAD PTR
    OUTPUT
    LOAD NODE4
    OUTPUT
    LOAD PTR
    OUTPUT
    LOAD NODES
    OUTPUT
    LOAD PTR
    OUTPUT
    HALT
```

Ive tried asking my classmates but they dont seem to know either

Comment: I've never heard of this language, so a total stab in the dark here but is the trailing comma before Jump the problem? The syntax I've seen doesn't follow that but I know nothing

Answer (score 2):

The tooling you're using doesn't like labels alone on a line.  Yes, this is silly, I generally prefer putting labels alone on the line, but it is what it is.

Change

```
PTR,  
JUMP Begin
```

to

```
PTR, JUMP Begin
```

And all the rest of the labels that are alone on the line as well.